# Tests fail ONLY on one python version, and the diffs only show README change. How's that possible?

Tags: python, testing, portability

I am developing a python package. Every commit is tested on Travis CI on python 3.5 and 3.6. At [one point](https://travis-ci.org/piccolbo/altair_recipes/builds/431913712), the tests started failing on 3.5 only. [Diffs](https://github.com/piccolbo/altair_recipes/compare/1cd71c4c450c...d8dab789a6fe) only show minor README changes. I rerun the build a couple of times with no change. The error logs show a discrepancy between the signatures of two functions. Since I am dynamically building these objects, I know the order of arguments depend on the stability of the `sorted` library function. This is the only hunch I have. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: guess: are you relying on the order of dictionaries? dicts became insertion-ordered in CPython 3.6

Comment: Excellent point. For the reason you mentioned I am using OrderedDicts but it's something I should review. Was the order arbitrary or random (non reproducible) in 3.5?

Comment: Tests pass now by eliminating all cases in which stable sorting would be needed, e.g. keys are distinct. Still @Chris_Rands' theory is the best, as sorted function is guaranteed stable in 3.5 and 3.6.

Comment: It's most likely an issue of ordering of kw args. Covered in PEP 468 and related to what @Chris_Rands mentioned but not the same thing. Now the question is why now? How can  a README change trigger this? Probably we will never know.